# Rviz crashing to login screen

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the command "rosrun rviz rviz", the screen flashes and I get dumped to the ubuntu login screen. I am running fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.

Some more details:

1. I have used ROS and rviz extensively before on this same computer.
2. The only thing I upgraded recently were the Primesense drivers.
3. I've already tried restarting the computer, and deleting the .rviz directory to reset the system.
4. The .ros/log files don't appear very informative. The last message I see in rosout.log is "Loading general config from [/home/{username}/.rviz/config]". Otherwise, the master.log has a message "keyboard interrupt, will exit" near the end.
5. OpenCV graphics appear to work fine. I can run programs that display color and/or grayscale images using native OpenCV without any problems.
6. I also tried reinstalling the ros-fuerte-visualization package without any effect.
7. I also tried the flag options (LIBGL and OGRE_RTT export commands shown on http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting), but get the same behavior.

What I'm hoping for is suggestions on where else to look in order to debug this. I'd rather not reinstall ros from scratch, but that's the next step... followed by a reinstall of the graphics drivers, and then ubuntu itself. Anything else I can do before having to commit to drastic reinstalls?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108946/rviz-crashing-to-login-screen/) by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're getting dumped to the login screen, that indicates that the entire X server is crashing and being restarted. You may want to look at the X logs in `/var/log/Xorg.*` and the kernel log (in `/var/log/dmesg` or run the `dmesg` command)

This could be caused by a change in the kernel, graphics drivers, or the X server. You may want to look at the package upgrade log at `/var/log/dpkg` for things to investigate.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1